# [ROS2] Close all threads when using CTRL-C

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
In my project I'm spawning a thread which contains a while loop, simply like so:

```
std::thread worker([this]() { this->ballotCheckingThread(); });
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->candidate_mutex_);
```

where the thread code is like this

```
void ballotCheckingThread() {
    while (!this->checkVotingCompleted() && !this->checkForExternalLeader()) {
        // Simulate some delay between checks
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }

    // Notify the first thread to stop waiting
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I use CTRL-C to terminate the node, this thread remains hanging and I have to manually kill it.

Right now in the main function I'm doing this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Starting  node..." << std::endl;
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node = std::make_shared<myNode>();
    rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor;
    executor.add_node(node);

    try {
        executor.spin();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "rclcpp shutting down..." << std::endl;
        rclcpp::shutdown();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

but I guess that's not enough. Is there a standard way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417513/%5Bros2%5D-close-all-threads-when-using-ctrl-c/) by [slim71](https://answers.ros.org/users/145981/slim71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2023-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end, I've found a solution.
Using a global variable `std::weak_ptr<MyNode> MyNode::instance_;`, I've initialized it in the main and registered it as a signal handler:

```
// Set the instance pointer to the shared pointer of the main node
MyNode::setInstance(node);
// Register the signal handler for SIGINT (CTRL+C)
signal(SIGINT, MyNode::signalHandler);
```

before adding and spinning the node.

I had to add some function to the node, of course:

```
class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node {
    public:
        std::atomic<bool> is_terminated_ {false};
        void stopThread();
        void startThread();
        static void signalHandler(int signum);
        static std::shared_ptr<MyNode> getInstance();
        static void setInstance(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr instance);
    private:
        std::thread helping_thread_;
        static std::weak_ptr<MyNode> instance_; // Weak pointer to the instance of the node
}

void MyNode::setInstance(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr instance) {
    instance_ = std::static_pointer_cast<MyNode>(instance);
}

std::shared_ptr<MyNode> MyNode::getInstance() {
    return instance_.lock();
}

void MyNode::signalHandler(int signum) {
    // Stop the thread gracefully
    std::shared_ptr<MyNode> node = getInstance();
        if (node) {
            node->stopThread();
        }

    rclcpp::shutdown();
}

void MyNode::startThread() {
    if (!this->helping_thread_.joinable()) {
        this->helping_thread_ = std::thread(&MyNode::spawnedThread, this);
    }
}

void MyNode::stopThread() {
    if (this->helping_thread_.joinable()) {
        this->is_terminated_ = true;
        this->helping_thread_.join();
    }
}
```

where `spawnedThread` is the main function used in the additional thread.

I don't really like using global variables and such, but for now this works as intended.

---

Originally posted by [slim71](https://answers.ros.org/users/145981/slim71/) with karma: 18 on 2023-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0